# Where can I go backcountry camping in southern Ontario Canada

Tags: camping, backcountry, canada

Looking for locations near London Ontario Canada, within a 2 hour drive where I can hike in and set up camp. I'd prefer to not have to go past Toronto because of the heavy traffic, if I can avoid it.

So far, I haven't found anything except provincial parks, where they don't allow camping except at designated areas. I've only found places near Algonquin, and again, that's pretty far out and past Toronto.

Comment: Slightly closer but still pretty far would be the [Queen Elizabeth II Wildlands Provincial Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_Elizabeth_II_Wildlands_Provincial_Park).  See also [this question on Travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/29018/2509).

Answer (score 2):

If you drove 3 hours there may be some possibilities along the Bruce Trail.  I'm unsure where you might be able to camp but you may want to check out this link from their website: http://brucetrail.org/pages/trail/camping

Comment: Thanks Stephen. The Terra Cotta Conservation area looks promising. I've also heard about camping along the Bruce trail. I'll call a few places and see.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help. I've purchased a Bruce Trail map and found Terra Cotta Conservation Area and Pretty River Valley Provincial Park with a camp spot in adjacent Petun Conservation Area. The latter is 2 hours away, but I think it'll suffice.

Comment: you generally cannot camp in conservation areas.

Comment: Hi @KateGregory. Thanks for the heads up. However, the Bruce Trail shows a designated spot where it is permitted.

Comment: Stack Exchange works different than forums. This "answer" would be much more appropriate as a comment on Stephen's answer. It's also good to accept his answer, since it seems to have addressed your problem.